# Simple find and replace with sed

Tags: bash

I'm trying to replace a number that is in a couple different strings in a text file.  Basically it would take the form of

```
tableNameNUMBER
carNUMBER
```

I'm pretty new to bash and scripting and I wasn't sure how to replace `NUMBER` with what I pass in.  So I've tried this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
sed "s/NUMBER/$1/" myScript.txt > test.txt
```

then at the command line:

```
sh test.sh 123456
```

This only works if `NUMBER` is on its own, without `tableName` or `car` preceding it.  How can I replace `NUMBER` in those cases.  Is it better to have `${NUMBER}`?  Sorry if these are totally noob questions.

Comment: That should work.  Perhaps you just need to add the g flag: `sed "s/NUMBER/$1/g"`

Comment: offtopic: why do you have a `bash` shebang line in a `sh` script which you also run explicitly using `sh test.sh`?

Comment: Also, is NUMBER an actual string, or is it an actual number?

Comment: try with:

    `#1 /usr/bin/env bash`

    `sed "s/(tableName\|car)NUMBER/\1$1/g" myScript.txt > test.txt`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
sed "s/NUMBER/$1/g" myScript.txt > test.txt
```

The `g` on the end allows set to replace NUMBER if it appears multiple times on one line.

In fact, a quick test:

#### foo.txt

```
carNUMBER
tableNameNUMBER
NUMBER
NUMBERfoo

$ NUMBER=3.14
$ sed "s/NUMBER/$NUMBER/g" foo.txt
car3.14
tableNumber3.14
3.14
3.14foo
```

Isn't that what your `sed` command is doing?

If you want to make sure you **don't** change NUMBER unless it's by itself, use `\b` around `NUMBER`:

```
$ sed "s/\bNUMBER\b/$NUMBER/g" foo.txt
carNumber
tabelNumberNUMBER
3.14
NUMBERfoo
```

If you don't care about the case of the string `NUMBER`, put an `i` on the end of the sed command:

```
$ sed "s/NUMBER/$NUMBER/gi" foo.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you've stated you're new to this, I'm going to first answer some problems that you haven't asked.

**Your *shebang* is wrong**

The first bytes of your script should be `#!` (a hash and an exclamation mark; referred to as a *shebang*).  You have `#1` (hash-one), which is gibberish.  This shebang line tells the system to use `bash` to interpret your file (i.e. your script) when executed. (More or less.  Technically speaking, it's actually given to `env`, which finds `bash` before handing it over.)

Once you've fixed up the shebang, set the permissions on the script to let the system know it's executable:

```
$ chmod a+x test.sh
```

Then run it like so:

```
$ ./test.sh 123456
```

As @gokcehan also commented, running your script with `sh ...` when you have a shebang is redundant, and isn't preferable for other reasons.

---

As for what you were asking, you can easily test your regex replacement:

```
$ echo tableNameNUMBER | sed "s/NUMBER/123456/"
tableName123456
```

And it seems to work just fine.

Note: The preceding `$` merely denotes that I typed it into my console and isn't part of the actual command.

Answer (score 1):

to replace 1111 to 2222 you should probably try

```
cat textfile.txt | sed -e 's/1111/2222/g'
```

or

```
cat textfile.txt | sed -e 's/1111/2222/g' > output.txt
```

or

```
NUMBER=1111 ; NEWNUMBER=2222; cat textfile.txt | sed -e "s/$NUMBER/$NEWNUMBER/g"
```

There's no need to create separate script for such trivial task. Note "-e" switch for sed, "g" appended at the end of quoted command, and the difference between single and double quotes.

Comment: No need to use cat: sed -e `s/1111/2222/g` textfile.txt` will do the same.