# Find and replace strings in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have XML file, this file has to be changed each time i'm running my scripts, i have to find a specific line there

`<data key='user.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value='/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/build'/>`

I can't be sure that this line will be at the same line number, is there any way to find this line, and replcae the value which is `'/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/build'`.

The input file that i have is:
`<data key='user.Common_AdminDir' value='/var/adm/rational'/>
    <data key='user.Common_TempDir' value='/tmp'/>
    <data key='user.CC_LICENSE_MANAGER,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value='IBMRCL'/>
    <data key='user.ATRIA_HOST_IS_REMOTE,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value=''/>
    <data key='user.ATRIA_REMOTE_HOSTNAME,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value=''/>
    <data key='user.ATRIA_LOCAL_KEY,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value=''/>
    <data key='user.CC_IS_ATRIA_LICENSE,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value='false'/>
    <data key='user.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value='/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/build'/>
    <data key='user.CC_MVFSModuleRebuild,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value='1'/>`

I need to replace the value that is in the line which holds the next string  - `MVFSModuleKernelPath,com.ibm.rational.clearcase` 
I don't know what is the current in this line so the search pattern can't include the the string in the value  -  and i need to replace it with a new value for example `echo /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build` this value will be in some variable `valueToInsert`
I want to be able to print just value in the virst place and put in some variable in order to compare with my existing kernel version and then replace it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash find and replace with sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735788/bash-find-and-replace-with-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
# printing current value
sed -n "\#<data key='user\.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com\.ibm\.rational\.clearcase\.linux_x86'#s~^.*value='\([^']*\)'.*$~\1~p" file.xml
/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/build

# replacement of the value by $valueToInsert
sed -i.bak "\#<data key='user\.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com\.ibm\.rational\.clearcase\.linux_x86'#s~^\(.*value='\)[^']*\('.*\)$~\1$valueToInsert\2~" file.xml
```

Comment: how can i just print the value in order to compare it before changing it

Comment: The print command that you've provided me is nt working there is a problem with the `[` , by the way i think that i haven't explained it in the correct way  -  i don't know what is the value in the line, so how can i just print the value it self i can be sure that this line is starting with this string `<data key='user.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value`

Comment: This one is printing the whole line how can i print just value which is in this case  -`/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/build`

Comment: The command for the replacement is replcaing but there is one problme it's printing the whole file how can i avoid ?

Comment: I was talking about this command `sed "\#<data key='user\.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com\.ibm\.rational\.clearcase\.linux_x86#s~/lib/modules/2\.6\.32-279\.el6\.i686/build~replacement~" file.xml`

Comment: I'm talking about the first command that you gave in your answer -  the ine that is replacing the value also  -  this command is replacing the value but it also printing the whole file

Comment: I've edited my question, let me know if it's ok for you

Answer (score 1):

Open file and use substitution replace value with "MY NEW VALUE".

WHere my "MY NEW VALUE" in the command line is your new value also using # as delimiter in sed instead of using "/" will avoid having to escape "/" chars.

```
 xmllint my_xml_file|sed 's#key='user.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value='/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/build'/>#key='user.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value= MY NEW VALUE/>#g'
```

To find line, highlight and print it and afterward modify and print the new line, you can try the following

```
 xmllint xml_file| grep -o -E --color  'key='user.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value='/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/build'/>' &&  xmllint my_xml_file|sed -n 's#key='user.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value='/lib/modules/2.6.32-279.el6.i686/build'/>#key='user.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86' value= MY NEW VALUE/>#p'
```

Comment: Not only is the `cat` useless, it prevents you from using `sed -i` to modify the file in place.

Comment: there is a problem with the commands that you've provided me, because i don't know what is the string in the value so search pattern can't include it, is there anyway to make without it ? could you also provide another command which is just printing the string in the value

Comment: sorry I was not home..however I am glad you have your answer..Cheers!