# Simple sed search and replace

Tags: windows, sed

I use `sed` vary rarely, perhaps once a year, and it always seems to take me hours to work out how to make it do even the simplest of tasks - a simple search/replace in a text file.

I need a single command line (for Windows) that will search for a simple string in a text file and replace all instances of that string with another.

For example - replace `&#x00a0;` with  in an xml file.

Comment: you need spend hours with `sed` for a simple usage,  you use `sed` very rarely,  you work on windows... then why do you pick `sed` for the task? you can just open the file in notepad++, editPlus, ultraedit...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash find and replace with sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735788/bash-find-and-replace-with-sed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i "s/&#x00a0;/ /g" 20151201120758.xml
```

- `sed` - invokes the program - remember to add it to your `path`.
- `-i` - inplace - modifies the original file.
- `"..."` - remember to add quotes if there are special chartacters in your regex such as  or `&`.
- `s/x/y/` - `s`earch for regex `x` and replace with string `y`.
- `.../g` - global search - without this it will only replce the first match.
- `xxx.yyy` - file to search - can use wild cards.

Comment: Single quotes would avoid even more expansion confusion.